# Does it matter where you declare Atoms when using Recoil?

Tags: recoiljs

I was going over the the *Getting Started* section of the docs, but it wasn't clear from the examples in which files the Atoms were being declared.

Does it matter *where* you declare a particular Atom in the app? If two components subscribe to the same Atom, can I declare the atom in one component's file or the other? Or do I need to declare it in both? Or do I need to declare it in a third file? Is there a best practice?

My intuition is telling me that I should declare these Atoms in a third file and import them to the components that need them, but I just want to be sure I'm understanding this correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generally the right approach to declare and export the recoil states (atoms/selectors/etc.) in one module, and then import them into the other component modules which use them. If you have a data structure that requires a different approach, it will be apparent to you.

You can research GitHub repositories in these topics to see examples and improve your confidence:

- [recoil](https://github.com/topics/recoil)
- [recoiljs](https://github.com/topics/recoiljs)